# Server Name Indication (SNI)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lamp, apache-2.2

Is it possible to use mod_vhost_alias with SNI? I know mod_vhost_alias usually works pretty late with the header (like mod_rewrite). Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.

Unfortunately, *mod_vhost_alias* does not have SSL/SNI support yet, so one of the problems is that there is no way to configure the certificates for each virtual host.

Comment: Is this still true in 2017? How about that: [digicert tutorial](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm)